# Pandas: Find the peak element in a Data frame with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, match

I have the Data frame with group of values 'A','B’,.. in column 'ID'.
Need to find the Peak element value from 'Value' column and where 'Type' is equal to low. The matched condition values are required to be populated in different columns ('Low_Peak_Value' & 'Peak_Time' columns), sample output is shown below, could anyone suggest how to do this.
column 'ID' has various set of values; hence this condition should be applying to each group in 'ID' column.

```
data = {'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
               'A'],
        'Date': ['2023-05-12 16:00:00', '2023-05-15 15:00:00', '2023-05-16 14:00:00', '2023-05-17 07:00:00',
                 '2023-05-17 20:00:00', '2023-05-18 02:00:00', '2023-05-18 16:00:00', '2023-05-19 07:00:00',
                 '2023-05-25 05:00:00',
                 '2023-05-26 01:00:00', '2023-05-26 16:00:00',
                 '2023-05-29 09:00:00', '2023-05-31 17:00:00', '2023-06-01 22:00:00', '2023-06-05 13:00:00',
                 '2023-06-06 03:00:00', '2023-06-06 15:00:00',
                 '2023-06-06 22:00:00', '2023-06-07 18:00:00', '2023-06-08 05:00:00', '2023-06-08 22:00:00',
                 '2023-06-09 11:00:00'],
        'Value': [89845, 90065, 89462, 89437, 89455, 89248, 89013, 89405, 88687, 88521, 88543, 88682, 87747, 88208,
                  88406, 88731, 89118, 89178, 88824, 88865, 89459, 89363],
        'Type': ['Low', '', '', 'Low', '', '', 'Low', '', '', 'Low', '', '', 'Low', '', 'Low', '', '', '', 'Low', '',
                 '', ''],
        'Low_Peak_Value': ['', 89845, 89845, 89845, 89845, 89845, 89845, 89845, 89845, 89845, 89845,
                           89845, 89845, 87747, 87747, 87747, 87747, 87747, 87747, 87747, 87747, 87747],
        'Peak_Time': ['', '2023-05-12 16:00:00', '2023-05-12 16:00:00', '2023-05-12 16:00:00', '2023-05-12 16:00:00',
                      '2023-05-12 16:00:00', '2023-05-12 16:00:00', '2023-05-12 16:00:00', '2023-05-12 16:00:00',
                      '2023-05-12 16:00:00', '2023-05-12 16:00:00', '2023-05-12 16:00:00', '2023-05-12 16:00:00',
                      '2023-05-31 17:00:00', '2023-05-31 17:00:00', '2023-05-31 17:00:00', '2023-05-31 17:00:00',
                      '2023-05-31 17:00:00', '2023-05-31 17:00:00', '2023-05-31 17:00:00', '2023-05-31 17:00:00',
                      '2023-05-31 17:00:00']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

Available Data:
**************
ID           Date          Value    Type        
A   12-05-2023 16:00:00    89845    Low         
A   15-05-2023 15:00:00    90065        
A   16-05-2023 14:00:00    89462        
A   17-05-2023 07:00:00    89437    Low 
A   17-05-2023 20:00:00    89455        
A   18-05-2023 02:00:00    89248        
A   18-05-2023 16:00:00    89013    Low 
A   19-05-2023 07:00:00    89405        
A   25-05-2023 05:00:00    88687        
A   26-05-2023 01:00:00    88521    Low 
A   26-05-2023 16:00:00    88543        
A   29-05-2023 09:00:00    88682        
A   31-05-2023 17:00:00    87747    Low 
A   01-06-2023 22:00:00    88208        
A   05-06-2023 13:00:00    88406    Low 
A   06-06-2023 03:00:00    88731        
A   06-06-2023 15:00:00    89118        
A   06-06-2023 22:00:00    89178        
A   07-06-2023 18:00:00    88824    Low 
A   08-06-2023 05:00:00    88865        
A   08-06-2023 22:00:00    89459        
A   09-06-2023 11:00:00    89363        

Required Output:
***************
ID           Date       Value   Type    Low_Peak_Value  Peak_Date   
A   12-05-2023 16:00:00 89845   Low         
A   15-05-2023 15:00:00 90065          89845        12-05-2023 16:00:00
A   16-05-2023 14:00:00 89462          89845        12-05-2023 16:00:00
A   17-05-2023 07:00:00 89437   Low    89845        12-05-2023 16:00:00
A   17-05-2023 20:00:00 89455          89845        12-05-2023 16:00:00
A   18-05-2023 02:00:00 89248          89845        12-05-2023 16:00:00
A   18-05-2023 16:00:00 89013   Low    89845        12-05-2023 16:00:00
A   19-05-2023 07:00:00 89405          89845        12-05-2023 16:00:00
A   25-05-2023 05:00:00 88687          89845        12-05-2023 16:00:00
A   26-05-2023 01:00:00 88521   Low    89845        12-05-2023 16:00:00
A   26-05-2023 16:00:00 88543          89845        12-05-2023 16:00:00
A   29-05-2023 09:00:00 88682          89845        12-05-2023 16:00:00
A   31-05-2023 17:00:00 87747   Low    89845        12-05-2023 16:00:00
A   01-06-2023 22:00:00 88208          87747        31-05-2023 17:00:00
A   05-06-2023 13:00:00 88406   Low    87747        31-05-2023 17:00:00
A   06-06-2023 03:00:00 88731          87747        31-05-2023 17:00:00
A   06-06-2023 15:00:00 89118          87747        31-05-2023 17:00:00
A   06-06-2023 22:00:00 89178          87747        31-05-2023 17:00:00
A   07-06-2023 18:00:00 88824   Low    87747        31-05-2023 17:00:00
A   08-06-2023 05:00:00 88865          87747        31-05-2023 17:00:00
A   08-06-2023 22:00:00 89459          87747        31-05-2023 17:00:00
A   09-06-2023 11:00:00 89363          87747        31-05-2023 17:00:00
```

Comment: Can you describe how the `87747` group differs from `89845` in your desired output?

Comment: I need to find the rolling peak low value where the 'Type ' column has the value low, since those are the extrema low values

Comment: Perhaps someone can explain why the peak value changes to `87747`? `89845` is the largest Low value (I assume this is what peak means) - but I don't understand why it changes to `87747` - the only thing I can see that changes is the month, does it reset each month?